# Mapping to a different view based on child type

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

So i have a situation where i have common base type but i need to map to a different view based on the child type.

It looks like i can use a generic mapping class to handle the inheritance

http://geekswithblogs.net/nharrison/archive/2010/07/09/inheriting-a-class-map-in-fluent-nhibernate.aspx

But how can i conditionally map to a different view based on the child type? I see an EntityType property but it says its obsolete and will be made private in the next version.

As an example i have a base class of ContactInfo is standard between contact types but the values come from different places depending on the contact type, this I'll handle through the sql view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using any mapping the referenced entity comes from a different table

```
class ContactInfo
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public ContactInfoMap
{
    ...
    ReferencesAny(x => x.Details)
        .EntityIdentifierColumn("details_id")
        .EntityTypeColumn("contactType")
        .IdentityType<long>()
        .AddMetaValue<FooContactDetails>("1")
        .AddMetaValue<BarContactDetails>("4");
}
```

Comment: I ended up just duplicating code for each entity. Which meant a map for each type